# Excel VBE inconsistent exports

Tags: excel, vba, svn, vbe

I am exporting `.bas` files from an `.xls` file as outlined here: [Exporting A VBComponent Code Module To A Text File](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) to check them in into an SVN repo.

I am encountering the following issue which causes a change in casing of variable names in the files that is actually not real (or at least not relevant).

Statements like these get reformatted/recased:

```
rngTenors.Cells(i, 1) 
changes into 
rngTenors.cells(i, 1)
```

(subtle but still different and it gets picked up by the diff tool that I use and hides the real changes on the file in the noise that this generates)

Any idea of ways to prevent this from happening would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing something similar but haven't seen what you are experiencing. I'm not using the same export routines but they look similar at first glance.

A couple of questions.

> 1) Are you using `option explicit`, and
>   do you have a variable named `cell`
>   anywhere?
>
> 2) If you Commit, then make a few changes, export the .bas file and Commit again, what does the diff look like?
>
> 3) Are you opening and diffing the .bas files in a code aware editor (eg: Ultraedit) that may be changing your capitalisation?

I'm just guessing... but VB editor capitalisation can be weird if you name variables the same as methods or properties. Also i don't see why your export would inconsistently export `.Cell` i'm guessing if it exports to `.cell` then it should always export to `.cell` and not be a problem.

These are just some ideas, good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for feedback Mark, I am using option explicit. I will search my code for a variable named cell tomorrow.

regarding 2), the diffs in general look like they should (except when this additional unwanted diff gets introduced).

3) I am using winmerge as my diffing tool (I think it is not code aware)

I think that the explanation with the 'conflicting' variable name sounds likely, will follow up on that, thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

The VBE keeps an internal cache of variable names, *including* the casing, so even though you found a variable called `cell`, and renamed it to be something else, VBA still *thinks* it is a valid name, and so it is preserving the casing across all usages of that *text*.

You can trick the VBE into resetting the variable casing (and this also works for casing problems on methods too) by temporarily declaring a variable with the correct casing:

```
Public Cell as String
```

And then deleting that variable. You should then find that all of the casings are fixed throughout your project (and any project that refers to it).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I found something in the code as was suggested above.

```
dim cell
```

I have now renamed this variable and no reformats have occurred since. I expect and hope that this has resolved the issue. Many thanks for help!